# Scar on Justin's neck

Tags: 13-reasons-why

After the shooting episode of season 4 of *13 Reasons Why*, when Jessica hit Justin with a stapler, he got injuries on his forehead. But after that, till the last episode, there was a visible scar on his neck like that of skin infected with fungi. It was not a scar of injury. Did they show how he got it or was it something that the actor had and they chose not to cover it for the character too?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in an interview with the director, he explained that they were **Kaposi's sarcoma (KS)**

> Lesions on the skin and/or internal organs caused by abnormal growth
> of blood vessels. In people living with HIV, Kaposi's sarcoma is an
> AIDS-defining cancer.

Hence, they hinted that Justin had HIV and the scars were willingly put on the character's skin.